# Using Model class in lmfit in combination with Parameter class

Tags: python, lmfit

I'm trying to fit some data using lmfit. Originally, I used the Model class which worked well based on this example/tutorial:
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html
But then I wanted to add some parameters constraints to the model, thus I looked at this tutorial:
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html

However, I've got some problems in combining the two classes such that they work nicely together.
Either it complains about the fit function missing parameters or getting invalid parameters (that's the case in the example I'll post) or I get a model which doesn't actually take the parameters I specified.
I can actually solve the problem using one of these different approaches:
1. Pass the paramaters using model.make_params(...), but I would like to split them up individually
2. I could use the Minimizer instead of Model, but I would like to understand why they are so differently implemented even though I would expect them to be very similar (except that they work on different type of input)

Any help / explanations would be really appreciated. :)

This code is based on the example on the Parameters tutorial page.
What I did here is to modify the example such that the Model class is used instead of the Minimizer class, which in principle should work, but I'm somehow doing it the wrong way.
As comparison, the original example is here (scroll to the bottom):
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/parameters.html

```py
# <examples/doc_parameters_basic.py>
import numpy as np

from lmfit import Model, Parameters

# create data to be fitted
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 301)
data = (5. * np.sin(2*x - 0.1) * np.exp(-x*x*0.025) +
        np.random.normal(size=len(x), scale=0.2))


# define objective function: returns the array to be minimized
def fcn2min(params, x):
    """Model a decaying sine wave and subtract data."""
    amp = params['amp']
    shift = params['shift']
    omega = params['omega']
    decay = params['decay']
    model = amp * np.sin(x*omega + shift) * np.exp(-x*x*decay)
    return model


# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()
params.add('amp', value=10, min=0)
params.add('decay', value=0.1)
params.add('shift', value=0.0, min=-np.pi/2., max=np.pi/2)
params.add('omega', value=3.0)

# do fit, here with leastsq model
fitmodel = Model(fcn2min)
result = fitmodel.fit(data, params, x=x)

# calculate final result
final = result.fit_report()

# try to plot results
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x, data, 'k+')
    plt.plot(x, final, 'r')
    plt.show()
except ImportError:
    pass
# <end of examples/doc_parameters_basic.py>
```

But using it like this, I get an error

```
ValueError: Invalid independent variable name ('params') for function fcn2min
```

I tried:
Specifying all parameters as function arguments, e.g.

```
def fcn2min(x, amp, shift, omega, decay):
```

But in this case I end up with the model / function parameters not being connected and I get a 'fit' which does nothing.

Now I tried stuff like specifying:

```
fitmodel = Model(fcn2min, independent_vars=['x'], param_names=params)
```

But in this case I get

```
Invalid parameter name ('amp') for function fcn2min
```

Also tried something like this:

```
params = fitmodel.make_params()
params.add('amp', value=10, min=0)
...
```

But in this case I also don't get parameters which are connected to the model, which can be seen from the output of

```
fitmodel.param_names
```

which returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing a model function as wrapped by the `Model` class for curve-fitting with an objective function for general purpose minimization with `minimize` or `leastsq`.    An objective function will have a signature like:

```
 def objective(params, *args):
```

where `params` is a `lmfit.Parameters` instance that you would have to unpack within the function and `*args` are optional arguments.  This function will return the array -- the objective -- that will be minimized in the least squares sense.

In contrast, a model function used to create a curve-fitting Model will have a signature like

```
 def modelfunc(x, par1, par2, par3, ..., **kws):
```

where `x` is the independent variable and `par1` ... will contain the *values* for the model parameters.   The model function will return an array that models the data.

There are lots of examples using objective functions and using model functions at
https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/tree/master/examples.   To model your data, you would do

```
# define MODEL **not objective** function: returns the array to model the data
def sinedecay(x, amp, shift, omega, decay):
    """Model a decaying sine wave""" . 
    return amp * np.sin(x*omega + shift) * np.exp(-x*x*decay)


# create model:
smodel = Model(sinedecay)

# create a set of Parameters
params = smodel.make_params(amp=10, decay=0.1, shift=0, omega=3)
params.set('amp', min=0)
params.set('shift',  min=-np.pi/2., max=np.pi/2)

# do fit
result = smodel.fit(data, params, x=x)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between the minimizer and the model function. Thing is: I was kind of hoping that I could avoid listing all of the parameters in the model function and could just pass the parameters to the model function like in the example. Also, is there a way to avoid having to define all parameters in one function call? Like running smodel.make_params() first and then add parameters sequentially?

Comment: For avoiding listing parameters: Nope, absolutely not.  That is how Model works (OTOH, `minimize` takes a `params` object as 1st argument). What you really do want is for the model function to be a "normal function" that takes regular named python arguments.  That way you can use it as a regular function to calculate any model you want.   `Model.make_params()` makes parameters based on the names of the function arguments.  Again, that is what you want.  You *can* (but don't have to) specify initial values with `make_params()` and/or add or modify them later.